# How can I detect the new line in String value?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have simple `TextField` widget that auto expands to a new line if the string width was almost near of max screen width.

Here is the code:

```
  TextEditingController textController  = TextEditingController();
    TextField(
      controller: textController,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      maxLines:null ,
      expands: true,
      maxLength: 200,
    )
```

**Question**: How can I detect the new line in `textController.text`?

E.g., we have the following sentence:

> The universe is the greatest mystery known to the
> human race

Notice that between `'the'` and `'human'` there is a new line.

I tried to output `textController.text` but there was nothing found like `\n` because the new line comes based on `UI` `rendering`.

How do I know that in code?

Comment: there aren't any break line in your `textController.text`. why do you want to get that?

Comment: because i want use the same layout from user inputs to another image using ffmpeg .

Comment: Did you try with if(_elementsController.text.endsWith('\n')) ??

Comment: @Anushka basically there aren't any break line in textController.text

Answer (score 0):

i found solution

by providing `globalKey` to the `textField` widget and listen to the it's height state . if there was change of the height so that's mean new line occurs

Answer (score 0):

My case:

```
TextField(
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
  maxLines: null, 
  onChanged: (text) {
    final numberOfNewLines = text.split('\n').length - 1;
    print('Number of new lines: $numberOfNewLines');
  },
);
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to detect new line:

```
onChange: (value) {
  if(value.endWith('\n')) {
     //your code 
   }
}
```